# I can't get instance of pos printer

Tags: epson, thermal-printer, pos-for-.net

I'm working on EPOS pos printer (EPOS TM-T88III). İ stalled it's driver, EPOS ADK and POS for .NET I can get print from my pos printer with PrintDocument function but i want to use EPOS ADK. I try its "Hello OPOS for .NET" sample but it's not work. 
Because,

```
deviceInfo = posExplorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter, strLogicalName)
m_Printer = posExplorer.CreateInstance(deviceInfo)
```

i can get deviceInfo but, posExplorer.CreateInstance(deviceInfo)  returns nothing. Icant solve this problem. 
How can i solve this problem to succeed returns something from posExplorer.CreateInstance(deviceInfo) or is there anyway or sample code to use EPOS ADK to print something.

Answer (score 0):

you have to tpyecast it to PosPrinter. that is the correct method.

```
m_Printer = (PosPrinter)posExplorer.CreateInstance(deviceInfo)
```

For samples: You will get many sample applications when you install the OPOS for .net ADK for EPSON. You can find those in your installation directory.

Also check your OS version and IDE used, the object initialization for PosPrinter wont happen for some OS and IDEs.