cannot print "Hello World" in EPSON printer
Hi im trying to simply print "Hello World" but I get an error "The value of the 'DevicePath' property must be defined by the service object before Open() can be called." and it points to this line printer.Open();
I am using .NET 4.8 and I have referenced the Microsoft.PointOfService; already. TIA.
using Microsoft.PointOfService;
using System;

namespace PrinterTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PosExplorer explorer = new PosExplorer();
            DeviceCollection devices = explorer.GetDevices(DeviceType.PosPrinter);

            Console.WriteLine("Checking for connected POS Printers...");
            foreach (DeviceInfo device in devices)
            {
                if (device.ServiceObjectName.IndexOf("TM-U220B", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("TM-U220B printer is connected!");

                    PosPrinter printer = (PosPrinter)explorer.CreateInstance(device);

                    printer.Open();

                    printer.Claim(1000);

                    printer.DeviceEnabled = true;

                    printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, "Hello World\n");

                    //printer.Cut(PosPrinterCutType.FullCut);

                    printer.Release();
                    printer.Close();

                    Console.WriteLine("Printed 'Hello World' successfully.");
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}


Did you compile as 32-bit as described here?

Did you debug that devices getting null ?

s https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68278999/cannot-create-instance-of-pos-printer any help?

Hi guys I wanna break it down 1 by 1 to figure out the problem. first the problem I encountered is regarding to the .NET version. I changed it to .NET 4.8 and it worked. now as I researched, it says to quickly know if everything works well I just need to run the TestApp.exe
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Point Of Service\SDK\Samples\Sample Application\TestApp.exe' but in my case it doesnt work. and it just said, DevicePath' property must be defined by the service object before Open() can be called.

@TharukaDeshan the devices is not null. I have fetched the printers that are installed in my machine and when I attached the printer to my pc it says connected to printer. the issue is that the "Hello World" print doesnt work.

The following may be of interest: https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/6go000/microsoft_pointofservice_printing_with_usb/?rdt=47932, https://parzibyte.me/blog/en/2023/01/09/send-bytes-thermal-printer-c-sharp-esc-pos/, https://github.com/lukevp/ESC-POS-.NET, and https://download4.epson.biz/sec_pubs/pos/reference_en/escpos/receipt.html, and
